# How to filter transactions in PoA/Clique chain

Tags: mining, poa, clique

(ETH noob here)

I am thinking of running [PoA/Clique based network](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) for a potential dApp project.

Is it possible for the sealer to apply filters on transactions before sealing a block?

The scenario is this.

- Trusted parties run sealers.
- Users issue transactions against smart contracts.
- **Users should not be able to spam the network with useless stuff inflating the blockchain.**

Some solutions that come to mind.

### Run chain on isolated network

Not really viable since I would like users to transact directly. Also having more (non-sealer) nodes should help the network propagate transactions quicker.

### Set high gas price

Only accounts with (fake) ETH can issue transactions. But I need to vet each account and issue them ETH to make transactions. This doesn't give me any way to validate transactions.

### Sealer only includes legit transactions

In this approach, the sealer would run some custom logic, like who is allowed to deploy new contracts, who can transact on particular contract, size limits, and so forth.

The question: Is there any way to set up the geth miner to apply custom logic to transactions before they get included into a block? If not then are there third party miners that allow me to do this *and* support Clique?

Just to be clear, my question is not regarding security, it's simply about reducing spam on the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own version of `geth`, where you add your custom logic in the Clique algorithm.

AFAIK, `geth` is the only client that supports Clique.